# Why the greedy approach works?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

the question:

> Given an array `nums` of positive integers, we can apply the operation of "merging" two adjacent elements, meaning that replace them with a single element containing their sum. (For example, if we merge the second and third elements of [1,2,3,4,5], we obtain [1,5,4,5].) Find the minimum number of merging operations such that the array is a palindrome.

It turns out that this can be solved with a two-pointers-greedy solution, as in this Python code:

```py
def minimumOperations(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) - 1
    moves = 0
    while left < right:
        if nums[left] == nums[right]:
            left +=1 
            right -=1 
            continue
        
        if nums[left] < nums[right]:
            nums[left+1] += nums[left]
            left +=1
        else:
            nums[right-1] += nums[right]
            right -=1
        
        moves +=1 

    return moves
```

The problem is that I don't quite understand *why* it's the best solution. Why does this give the right answer?

Comment: @KellyBundy, example `[2, 1, 1, 3]` can turn into `[3, 1, 3]` by merging the two left elements

Answer (score 4):

The greedy algorithm performs the minimum number of merges to the outer numbers.

Imagine any palindrome result that involves *more* than the minimum number of merges to the outer numbers, so if the greedy algorithm produces `[x, ... ,x]`, for example, then the other palindrome would be `[x+y, ... , x+y]`  This would obviously not be an optimal solution, since `[x,y, ..., y,x]` could be formed with 2 fewer merges.

The greedy algorithm, therefore, optimally forms the outer numbers of the palindrome.

Once the outer numbers are determined, the same argument applies to the remainder in the middle, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the loop step-by-step. First, we have this pseudocode (which I slightly changed to be recursive):

```
if (nums[left] == nums[right]):
    recurse on nums[left + 1:right - 1]
    return
```

This is fairly simple: if the outermost part of the array is already matching, then we can get the entire array to be a palindrome if we make the inner array a palindrome. In English, you could say that we would know that "racecar" is a palindrome if we know that (a) the first r == the last r and (b) "aceca" is a palindrome.

Then, we have this:

```
if (nums[left] < nums[right]):
    nums[left] += nums[left + 1]
    del nums[left + 1]
else:
    nums[right] = nums[right - 1]
    del nums[right - 1]

moves += 1
recurse on nums
```

First, notice that I've changed your code a little bit by deleting the unmerged number after merging. Anyways, this piece of code finds the smaller number of `nums[left]` and `nums[right]` and tries to merge said smaller number with an adjacent number so it can hopefully be equal to the bigger number. Basically, you keep merging small numbers until `nums[left] == nums[right]`; at that point, you repeat the process until the entire array is a palindrome.

Now, let's answer your question: *why* does this greedy approach work? Notice that your greedy approach works by getting the two outermost numbers to match and then recursing on the inner array between those numbers. We can clearly see that the greedy approach makes the two outermost numbers match in the minimum number of merges; merging the larger of `nums[left]` and `nums[right]` with any other number will not make any progress. Since the greedy approach does the best possible job of matching the 2 outermost numbers, the greedy approach would fail if and only if it could be more efficient to match 2 numbers that aren't the outermost numbers.

Let us consider the trivial case in which the outermost numbers are already matching; in this case, the greedy approach would skip over these numbers and make 0 merges. The greedy algorithm therefore can not be beat in this case.

Now comes the hard part: the case in which the outermost numbers do not match. The greedy algorithm takes the minimum number of merges to make these two numbers match. If there was an algorithm better than the greedy algorithm, it would have to do something different here; that is, the algorithm can't try to match the 2 outermost numbers in the minimum number of merges. However, it'll eventually have to do at N merges (where N >= 1) to get the 2 outermost numbers to be matching.

Let's call these N merges the "outermost merges" since they involved the outermost numbers. The outermost merges could have been done by the greedy approach. Furthermore, any merges before the outermost merges involving the second-outermost numbers could have been done by the greedy approach after the greedy approach did the outermost merges. We can extend this to the third-outermost numbers and so on. Basically, if there *was* an algorithm better than the greedy algorithm, the greedy algorithm could just do that algorithm in reverse. Doing it in reverse changes nothing since addition is commutative.

Now, you might say that the smart algorithm could have merged some inner numbers that the greedy approach wouldn't be able to reach. But, since the outermost numbers are now matching, we can reduce the problem to the inner array between the outermost numbers. Then, either the new outermost numbers are matching, or the smart algorithm would have to make merges involving the outermost numbers. At that point, you could just use the greedy approach as described before.

Comment: FWIW, deleting the unmerged number is not required (and was not included in OP's solution) since the problem only asks for the minimum number of operations, not the resulting palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

Since addition is associative, another way to think about the problem is that we want to split the array into a sequence of subarrays whose sums form a palindrome — for example, the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] gets split into [1+2+3, 4+5, 6] — and we specifically want the *longest* such sequence of subarrays. The answer will then be the length of the original array minus the length of this sequence. (Do you see why?) And we do know that this is possible to do, because if nothing else, we can always take the sequence where the entire array has been reduced to one element: [1+2+3+4+5+6]. (Note: I won't prove here that there's a *unique* longest sequence satisfying the palindrome requirement; but there's at least one such sequence, and there are finitely many possible sequences, so there must at least be a unique longest length of sequences that satisfy the requirement. As it happens, there *is* a unique longest sequence satisfying the requirement, but we don't actually need that fact, because we only care about the length.)

---

Now, let's start with the case that the first and last elements of the array have the same value, so it looks like [m, ..., m]. In theory, there are five possibilities for what the final sequence could look like:

1. The first and last elements each end up on their own, in single-element subarrays.

   - This is what the greedy solution assumes, and will turn out to be correct.
2. The first element ends up on its own, in a single-element subarray, but the last element ends up as part of a larger subarray.

   - This doesn't work out, because we know that all the elements are positive integers, so in any sequence like this, the first subarray will have sum *m* and the last subarray will have a sum that's greater than *m*, so it won't be a palindrome.
3. The first element ends up as part of a larger subarray, but the last element ends up on its own, in a single-element subarray.

   - This doesn't work out, for the same reason as #2.
4. The first and last elements each end up in larger subarrays, but not the same subarray.

   - This may result in a palindrome, but if so it'll be a palindrome of the form [m+n+..., ..., ...+p+m], which implies that [m, n+..., ..., ...+p, m] would also be a palindrome, where the latter sequence is longer. So this will never result in the *longest* palindrome.
5. The first and last elements end up in the same subarray, which spans the entire array.

   - Similarly to the previous, this will be a palindrome, but it will never be the *longest* palindrome, because we know that [m, ..., m] would be a longer palindrome.

So longest_sequence([m, ...rest..., m]) equals [m, ...longest_sequence(rest)..., m]; and the value we want, len([m, ...rest..., m]) − len(longest_sequence([m, ...rest..., m])), equals len(rest) − len(longest_sequence(rest)).

---

Next, consider the case that the first element of the array has a lesser value than the last element: [m, ..., p], where m < p.

Now, if those are the only two elements ([m, p]), then the only palindromic sequence is [m+p].

But if there are more elements, then we may have more options. So consider [m, n, ..., p]. We know that in any sequence, the last subarray will have a sum of at least p (because all the elements are positive), so in any *palindromic* sequence, the first subarray will have a sum that is *greater* than m, which means that the first subarray must also include n. So longest_sequence([m, n, ...rest..., p]) equals longest_sequence([m+n, ...rest..., p]), and the value we want, len([m, n, ..., p]) − len(longest_sequence([m, n, ..., p])), equals 1 + len([m+n, ..., p]) − len(longest_sequence([m+n, ..., p])).

We can combine these two possibilities — the "only two elements" subcase and the "more elements" subcase — into one: in both subcases, longest_sequence([m, n, ...rest...]) equals longest_sequence([m+n, ...rest...]), so the value we care about, len([m, n, ...rest...]) − len(longest_sequence([m, n, ...rest...])), equals 1 + len([m+n, ...rest...]) − len(longest_sequence([m+n, ...rest...])).

---

The case that the first element of the array has a *greater* value than the last element is similar; I won't bother walking through it.

So, that gives a simple recursive solution:

```
def minimumOperations(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    if len(num) <= 1:
        return 0
    else if nums[0] == nums[-1]:
        return self.minimumOperations(nums[1:-1])
    else if nums[0] < nums[-1]:
        copy = nums[1:]
        copy[0] += nums[0]
        return 1 + self.minimumOperations(copy)
    else:
        copy = nums[:-1]
        copy[-1] += nums[-1]
        return 1 + self.minimumOperations(copy)
```

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Pythonist at all, I apologize for any stupid mistakes.)

The greedy algorithm that you've posted is essentially just a translation of the above into iterative form rather than recursive, though it's much more efficient (O(*n*) instead of O(*n*<sup>2</sup>)) because it doesn't repeatedly take slices of the array (each of which does an O(*n*) copy).